# How to save leading zeroes (zeroes in prefix), to a number field, in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, prefix, zero

I have an integer field(bank account number). while saving it in rails, if it's containing any preceeding zero'es, then the zeroes are getting trimmed (removed) by rails automatically like below.

```
.gems :086 > bank_detail = BankDetail.new
 => #<BankDetail id: nil, account_name: nil, account_no: nil, bank_name: nil, branch_name: nil, ifsc_code: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
.gems :087 > bank_detail.account_no = "0123456"
 => "0123456" 
.gems :089 > bank_detail.save(:validate => false)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "bank_details" ("account_no", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["account_no", 123456], ["created_at", "2018-07-17 15:47:35.062139"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-17 15:47:35.062139"]]
   (22.7ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
.gems :090 > 
.gems :090 > BankDetail.last
  BankDetail Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "bank_details".* FROM "bank_details"  ORDER BY "bank_details"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<BankDetail id: 21, account_name: nil, account_no: 123456, bank_name: nil, branch_name: nil, ifsc_code: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2018-07-17 10:17:35", updated_at: "2018-07-17 10:17:35"> 
.gems :091 >
```

**As the bank account number contains leading zeroes,i want to make rails to save the number field, along with the prefixed zeroes. how can i do that?**

Comment: saving as string will work if you are fine

Comment: Account numbers are not essentially numbers. You might want to store them as strings.

Comment: This reminds me of questions asking why their hex numbers keep reverting to integers. :)

Comment: You *can't* store a numeric field with leading zeros. `123 == 0123 == 00123 == 000123 == ...`. Use a String: `"123" != "0123" != "00123" != "000123" != ...`

Answer (score 6):

The answer is pretty simple: A bank account number might look like a number but it shouldn't be stored in as an integer. Use a string column instead.

The rule of thumb is: Do not use integer columns for numbers when math doesn't make sense on that number type - like account numbers, postal codes, serial numbers

Comment: I've seen people store phone numbers as integers. :facepalm:

Comment: But yeah, I was going to post this rule of thumb. I'll upvote yours  instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `account_no` field is numeric in database.
You can make migration to make it string.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to string type for `account_no` column. Then you can use `.to_i` to convert `'0000123'` to `123` if you need.

Comment: Ah, careful there. `.to_i` does the right thing, but, say, `Integer('0000123')` does __another__ right thing.